# Geometric series summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I’ve got to prove that

$\sum_{n=1}^{15} 3(\frac 23)^n -1 = -9.014$ 
to 4sf

But keep on getting an answer that is out by about 3 (-6.001) 
Please could someone help and show me the right steps.
I’ve tried separating it out into an arithmetic and geometric but I don’t think that I’ve done it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \sum_{n=1}^{15} \biggl[3\biggl(\frac 23 \biggl)^n -1 \biggl] \\
= & 3\sum_{n=1}^{15} \biggl(\frac 23 \biggl)^n -\sum_{n=1}^{15}1 \\
= & 3 \times \frac{\frac 23 - \bigl(\frac 23 \bigl)^{16}}{1-\frac 23} - 15 \\
= & 9 \biggl( \frac 23 - \Bigl(\frac 23 \Bigl)^{16} \biggl) - 15\\
= & -9.01370...
\end{align}

---

In general, the way to sum $a+a^2+a^3+ \cdots + a^k$ is to let

$$S=a+a^2+a^3+ \cdots + a^k \;$$

Then

$$aS=a^2+a^3+a^4+ \cdots + a^{k+1} \;$$

Subtracting the two equations, we get

$$S-aS = a-a^{k+1}$$

where $S-aS = S(1-a)$, so

$$S = \frac{a-a^{k+1}}{1-a}$$

In this case, $a=\frac 23$ and $k = 15$.

Comment: Sorry to ask but why has it been raised to the power of 16 in the second bit

Comment: Hope that makes it clear

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome (as long as you give me the tick XD)